# Propagating arguments to decorator which combines other decorators

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have a scenario like:

```
@decorator_one(1)
@foo
@bar
def my_decorated_func():
    pass
```

I am trying to condense this into something like:

```
@my_custom_decorator(1)
def my_decorated_func():
    pass
```

This is straightforward if I have decorators that do not have `(1)` option:

```
def my_custom_decorator(f):
    @decorator_one
    @foo
    @bar
    def wrapped():
        pass
    return wrapped
```

However I am uncertain how to properly propagate the argument to the first wrapper.

In this case, I am comfortable assuming that if I pass 1 to my_custom_decorator that it will always and only be the arg for decorator_one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@decorator_one(1)` means that there is a callable that returns a decorator; call it a decorator *factory*. `decorator_one(1)` returns the decorator that is then applied to the function.

Just pass on the arguments from your own decorator factory:

```
def my_custom_decorator(*args, **kwargs):  # the factory
    def decorator(f):                      # the decorator
        @decorator_one(*args, **kwargs)
        @foo
        @bar
        def wrapped():
            pass
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

I used `*args, **kwargs` to pass on arbitrary arguments to the wrapped decorator factory `decorator_one()`, but you could also use explicitly named paramaters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a decorator factory.

I found the solution using a class more attractive because it separates the factory and the decorator:

```
class my_custom_decorator(object):

    __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # the factory
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    __call__(self, f):  # the decorator
        @decorator_one(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        @foo
        @bar
        def wrapped():
            pass

        return wrapped
```